# Something wrong with PointCloud indexes

Tags: angular, three.js

I have set up a point cloud with the intention of changing a vertex colour when the point is clicked. I have worked out how to set up the vertex colours and the index required but it just does not seem to add up as no colour ever changes and I can't seem to make sense of the index values I am getting.

```
 public createPointCloud(){
    const numberThree = 3;
    const vertices = new Float32Array(this.data.length * numberThree);
    const colours = new Float32Array(this.data.length * numberThree);
    const indices = new Uint16Array(this.data.length);

    let indexByThree = 0;
    let index = 0;
    let colorValues: number[] = [this.originalColour.r, this.originalColour.g, this.originalColour.b];

    this.data.forEach(line => {
      let cords: number[] = [line.XX, line.YY, line.ZZ];
      let iArray = [indexByThree];

      vertices.set(cords, indexByThree);
      colours.set(colorValues, indexByThree);
      indices.set(iArray, index);

      indexByThree += numberThree;
      index++;
    });

    this.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    this.geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, numberThree));
    this.geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colours, numberThree, true));
    this.geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1));
    this.geometry.scale(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    this.geometry.computeBoundingBox;
    this.geometry.center();

    this.points = new THREE.Points(this.geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({size: this.pointSize, vertexColors: true}));    
    this.scene.add(this.points);
  }
```

Please answer the question on the above; what should the index array get set for each index. In the above code I am increasing each index by three including the value placed in the index array so that it increases 0, 3, 6 etc. Is this correct as indexes don't appear to match when I debug through this. I have tried just incrementing the value but does not seem to make a difference.

When I pick a point from the cloud this is the code I use:

```
public onMouseDown(event) {

    var mousePosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    mousePosition.setX(2 * (event.clientX / this.container.nativeElement.clientWidth) - 1);
    mousePosition.setY(1 - 2 * (event.clientY / this.container.nativeElement.clientHeight));

    this.caster.setFromCamera(mousePosition, this.camera);
    const intersections = this.caster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children, true);

    if (intersections && intersections.length > 0) {

      var intersection = intersections[0];
      this.geometry.attributes.color[intersection.index] = this.highlightedColour.r;
      this.geometry.attributes.color[intersection.index + 1] = this.highlightedColour.g;
      this.geometry.attributes.color[intersection.index + 2] = this.highlightedColour.b;
      this.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
      // this.points.material.needsUpdate = true;
      
    }    
    console.log("Mouse is down! " + mousePosition.x + " " + mousePosition.y + " " + intersections.length);
  }
```

No change in the vertex colour after this code. As you can see I have tried a couple of different updates but everything I read states that the current line `this.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;` should be setting the renderer to update the vertex colours.

All I can think at this point is that I have not set up properly. Can anyone give me a heads up here please?

[Update]

I can now pick points and change the vertex colour. Its just not the correct one each time. This does not seem to be affected by altering the indexByThree to Index in the geometry set up code. Either setting up the indices is wrong or I am setting up the raycaster incorrectly and picking the wrong points.

[Update]

It is the picking set up that is incorrect. I had:

```
var mousePosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    mousePosition.setX(2 * (event.clientX / this.container.nativeElement.clientWidth) - 1);
    mousePosition.setY(1 - 2 * (event.clientY / this.container.nativeElement.clientHeight));
```

and the picking is always off in, what looks like, a set distance each time. If I change it to:

```
 var mousePosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    mousePosition.setX(2 * (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) - 1);
    mousePosition.setY(1 - 2 * (event.clientY / window.innerWidth));
```

because window.innerWidth/Height is what I am using for the aspect ratio but it is offset in the other direction. I think the question becomes what values should I use for the aspect ratio and this code?

Comment: Generally WebGL points are not used with indices – each point in the position attribute is a rendered point. Indices are used to identify the vertices used in primitives with multiple vertices, like triangles and lines. Try removing the indices here and drawing or updating colors?

Comment: let iArray = [indexByThree]; Shouldn't it be [index] there? This example is a bit different but on line 104 it sets the index for each vertex with an incrementing number. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_raycasting_points.html

Comment: @EthanHermsey Yes I noticed that and have changed it leaving the by three version in the snippet is a typo. I have this issue either way but I agree that index should be the correct value there.

Comment: Moving forward I am now changing the colour of points in the point cloud. Just the wrong ones so back to my original question what have I got wrong with the indexes. I am now using the single increment and again see no change if I use the by three version. The issue for changing was the array I wasn't accessing:
this.geometry.attributes.color.array[intersection.index] = this.highlightedColour.r;

Comment: IndexByThree seems to be the correct index as I get the right colour with that one. If I use index by one I get green or blue which suggests it is hitting the wrong values. This is still on the completely incorrect point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out now and there were a couple of things interacting to mess it up for me.

1. The position set up was good and the correct index appears to be indexByThree (0,3,6 ...)
2. After trying them both I have finally used `window.inner[Width | Height]` for aspect etc
3. Setting the colour change through the geometry object seems to be the way to update correctly `this.geometry.attributes.color.setXYZ( ... )` works as I have three colour values
4. Not forgetting to set `needsUpdate()` where required
5. Adjust the css so that the canvas is set to the full screen size

This last one was my last problem (causing the pick to change the colour of the wrong point) and was caused by mat-dialog-container having a css rule for padding set to 24px. Now the docs recommend not to remove this but it is the only way I have got this to work. I think the padding was included in the co-ords for picking so was always out by 24px when it selected the points.